# facing issue in our automation system when one app wants to communicate with other app using the AppleEvent from MacOS 10.14

Tags: automation, macos-catalina, macos-mojave, appleevents

I am facing issue in our automation system when one app wants to communicate with other app using the AppleEvent.
We have one automation utility (QASoapLib.app) which is present on the mac client machine in which the tests are performed on the software (MySoftware.app)
I am facing a issue when the utility app fires the test on MySoftware.app.
The communication between the QASoapLib and MySoftware.app happens using the Apple events. Whenever the QASoapLib fires command to new MySoftware.app build for the first time,
Apple OS throws a permission dialog saying
"QASoapLib.app" wants access to control "MySoftware.app". Allowing control will provide access to documents and data in "MySoftware.app", and to perform actions within that app"
If we press on Ok button then the communication between both happens and MySoftware.app starts to run the tests. this alert does not come for that build again.
But the alert always appear for every new MySoftware.app build in the system. It becomes a blocking issue for the automation.
What should I do to resolve this issue?